# Query embedded document using slug array in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have 3 models, that all have use the gem - https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug - that creates a _slugs field from the models title field.

I have the slug for one of my articles and I need to find the issue it belongs to. I have tried a whole deal of things, but nothing seems to work.

**Any advice on what the correct query is to get the issue that belongs to the article with my article slug?**

**Query that doesn't work:**

```
p = Publication.find("my-publication")
p.issues.where(:'articles._slugs'.in => ["an-article-slug"]).first
```

**Publication model:**

```
class Publication
  # 1. Include mongoid stuff
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  # 2. Define fields
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :published, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :live, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :show_walkthrough, type: Boolean, default: true
  field :subscription_duration, type: String, default: "Subscription Duration"
  field :subscription_price, type: String, default: "Price"
  field :sell_issues_separately, type: String, default: "Individual Issue Sale"
  field :issue_price, type: String, default: "Price"
  field :previewed_on_device, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :shareable, type: String, default: "Make Articles Shareable Online"
  field :urban_airship_key, type: String
  field :urban_airship_secret, type: String
  field :urban_airship_master_secret, type: String

  # 3. Set attributes accesible
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :live, :published, :show_walkthrough, :subscription_duration, :subscription_price, :sell_issues_separately, :issue_price, :cover_image_attributes, :logo_image_attributes, :shareable, :urban_airship_key, :urban_airship_secret, :urban_airship_master_secret

  # 4. Set slug
  slug :title, reserve: ['new', 'edit', 'walkthrough', 'email', 'previewer', 'privacy', 'support', 'manifest', 'feed', 'demo', 'existence', 'switch']

   # 5. Set associations
  belongs_to :user
  embeds_many :issues, order: :created_at.desc, cascade_callbacks: true

end
```

**Issue model:**

```
class Issue
  # 1. Include mongoid stuff
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  # 2. Define fields
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :published, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :last_push_at, type: DateTime, default: Time.now
  field :published_at, type: DateTime, default: Time.now
  field :no, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :color, type: String
  field :free, type: Boolean, default: false


  # 3. Set attributes accesible
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :published, :last_push_at, :published_at, :no, :color, :free, :cover_image_attributes

  # 4. Set slug
  slug :title, scope: :publication, reserve: ['new', 'edit', 'publish', 'update_order']

  # 5. Set associations
  embedded_in :publication
  embeds_many :articles, :as => :articleable, :class_name => 'Article', cascade_callbacks: true, order: :no.desc
  embeds_one :cover_image, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', cascade_callbacks: true, autobuild: true

end
```

**Article model:**

```
class Article
  # 1. Include mongoid stuff
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  # 2. Define fields
  field :title, type: String
  field :author, type: String
  field :lead, type: String
  field :body, type: String
  field :no, type: Integer

  # 3. Set attributes accesible
  attr_accessible :title, :author, :lead, :body, :no, :article_image_attributes, :article_images_attributes, :article_images_attributes

  # 4. Set slug
  slug :title, scope: :articleable

  # 5. Set associations
  embedded_in :articleable, polymorphic: true
  embeds_one :article_image, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', cascade_callbacks: true, autobuild: true
  embeds_many :article_images, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', cascade_callbacks: true

end
```

**UPDATED With new queries and results**

**I can get the publication using the query suggestion of @mu below:**

[image: Querying for publication]

**I can't get the issue using the same query though:**

[image: Querying for issue]

**And here you can see the _slugs field if I take the first article in the first issue of the publication:**

[image: Slugs field in article]

**What am I doing wrong here? The query seems to work nicely when grabbing a publication. Why doesn't it work nicely when grabbing an issue?**

Comment: I think I misread your question, sorry about that.

Comment: Are you sure that this slug thing you're using creates a `_slug` field? I see a `field :slug` in `Article`...

Comment: Arh ya. That was something I was experimenting with. The line "slug :title, scope: :article able", makes a _slug array field with slugs in. I've taken away the :slug field again, so now we only have the _slugs field left. Your query works great to get the publication. How do I make it work to get the issue that the article belongs to?

Comment: Can you dig the queries out of the moped logs? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.